# working dockingstation for lenovo carbon x1

Tags: usb, lenovo

it seems as that the [usb 3.0 Docking Station](http://shop.lenovo.com/deweb/de/de/itemdetails/0A33971/460/6D501EE899104FF9A362D739642CFC27) (using a Displaylink DL-3000 series chipset ) i got with my lenovo [will not work any time soon](http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?p=69372#post69372).  So I was hoping that somebody could give me advice on a proven/working chipset/working usb dockingstation (or any other way/workaround).

The goal should be to get 2 external Displays running, since i want to use it at my workplace as a replacement for my ubuntu workstation pc.

Comment: Looks like DisplayLink is now supporting Ubuntu: http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1748&page=20

Answer (score 1):

The [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/) will allow you to run two monitors from your laptop with Linux.